# Undo setting proxy via Settings.Global in Android

Tags: android, proxy

I am writing system app, which sets global http proxy via

```
Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1");
```

How can I revert this change? 
This don't work:

```
Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.HTTP_PROXY, null);
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Andrews answer works but only for rooted devices, here's my solution for non-rooted devices.

I added the proxy with the following command:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy <ip>:<port>
```

**Update:** To remove it you can use the following command (thanks to Rohit Patel for providing this):

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
```

<strike>To remove it I used these commands:</strike>

```
adb shell settings delete global http_proxy
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_host
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_port
```

Restart the device and you should be good to go

Comment: There is only tow options put&get in android 4.4

Comment: Is there a way to undo the proxy in real time, without restarting? Adding the proxy happens in real time but not removing it.

Comment: Does it support proxy credentials? And is it possible to use a SOCKS proxy instead of an HTTP proxy? Otherwise we would have to use workarounds by using an upstream proxy with other proxies.

Comment: For rooted devices you can call `am broadcast -a android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE` to force proxy refresh without having to reboot.

Comment: See answer from Rohit Patel below for an approach that obviates the need to restart device or broadcast PROXY_CHANGE: `adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0`

Comment: Okay, how to set proxy with authentication?

adb shell settings put global http_proxy <ip>:<port>:<login>:<password> - it's not working

Comment: FYI: these settings do not show up if you manually go to your phones' proxy setting ;-)

Comment: Didn't work for me. Android 9. When I check through the Wifi, It still has no proxy set.

Answer (score 21):

Below is the normal command to remove proxy settings which will be applied without device reboot. You can use it in your script or app relatively.

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
```

You don't need to run all three of those commands. It will work with just the one command above. All proxy settings will be removed instantly.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I had a hell of a time undoing my proxy hack so I figured I'd share.

I passed permissions to the device using ADB that would let me change the values to my proxy settings with my own custom application.

The problem is once I used my app with

```
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:8007");
```

It wouldn't let me set it back to default (No Proxy) no matter what I tried (null, blank, "NONE") basically if I wasn't connected through the proxy it wouldn't talk to the outside world. Even after restart.

SOLUTION I FOUND:

These settings are stored in a SQL database so when the phone restarts it applies them. You just need to go into the database and delete these rows from the table. What I did:

```
~user$ adb shell
shell@cinco:/ $ su -
```

FYI...Not sure if you need super user but it can't hurt right . . .

```
root@cinco:/ $ sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

you can see the full list of what's in the global table by doing:

```
sqlite> select * from global;
```

in the list you should be able to see the values you wrote in for http_proxy, global_http_proxy_host, and global_http_proxy_port, maybe you know what magic values to set these to so that it works properly, but I do not... my solution, just delete them:

```
sqlite> delete from global where name="global_http_proxy_host";
sqlite> delete from global where name="global_http_proxy_port";
sqlite> delete from global where name="http_proxy";
```

restart the phone and like magic there is no more proxy and I get the interwebs!!

Answer (score 2):

Andrew R's method is very constructive, because it shows that when you change the key "HTTP_PROXY", the system will automatically add two additional keys. But when you delete "HTTP_PROXY", the system won't automatically delete the additional keys, so when you only delete "HTTP_PROXY" it's not work.

Now that we know the cause, we can use following commands to remove proxy completely:

```
adb shell
$ su
# settings delete global http_proxy
# settings delete global global_http_proxy_host
# settings delete global global_http_proxy_port
```

I think it's a feature(bug) of android.

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.Secure.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:8007");
```

note `'Settings.Secure.putString()'`

Answer (score 0):

Another way instead of using root commands (you still need root though) and using the method of

```
Settings.Global.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1");
```

is to set the value to `:0` so it would look like this

```
Settings.Global.putString(activity!!.contentResolver, Settings.Global.HTTP_PROXY, ":0")
```

I didn't have to reboot either for the changes to take effect